# Computer starts with No Display

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, lcd

When i start my desktop, after i login into my account, i cannot see anything except a mouse cursor. The computer is ON which i confirmed by opening up the task manager. I cannot even see the task bar. Then after a few minutes the task bar is loaded and then the wallpaper & icons come up.

I guess, it has to be done with graphics of the PC or the monitor because the PC boots properly.

Also since last few days, my monitor threws the error of

> Display driver stopped responding and has recovered

What could be the actual problem & the solution?

Comment: Not a single comment?

Comment: Have you tried booting to safe mode, it sounds like the video driver is bad and need replaced. I would boot to safe mode and install the latest driver for you video card. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, i tried booting into safe mode and it was running OK. Why is video card bad, don't u think its graphics card thats creating a problem?

Comment: video card and graphics card is one in the same, my first try would be to replace the driver hopefully that will resolve your problems.

Comment: oh! thats silly... The graphics driver that i have is Intel(R) HD Graphics

Comment: I am not real sure what is silly, either a built in graphics chip or a video card have drivers and if you have Display Driver Error of any kind I would replace that driver to attempt to eliminate that as a cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see the cursor and can see the task manager, this usually simply means that you have a (blocking) startup program which is taking its time to fully load - such as AV, Firewall or similar.

As for the "Display driver stopped" error, I don't really have much hope for Intel HD recently [and have blogged about it here](http://blog.williamhilsum.com/2011/05/recommend-against-intel-core-i7-2600k.html).

I can't really suggest anything for the problems with the graphics, but I believe that these two problems are unrelated.